# Unable to get results from H2 db

Tags: java, h2, h2db

I'm trying to get values from h2 db, but always getting this error

```
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: No data is available [2000-171]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:135)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.checkOnValidRow(JdbcResultSet.java:2956)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.get(JdbcResultSet.java:2962)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet.getInt(JdbcResultSet.java:306)
```

I googled for an answer

> Make sure to call rs.next(); prior to using any of the getter methods.

But I do call rs.next() ...

Here's my code:

```
public User getUser(int userId) throws SQLException {
    User u = new User(userId);

    try {
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM invited_users WHERE user_id=" + userId);
        rs.next();

        u.setName(rs.getString("user_name"));

    } catch (SQLException except) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to load user! " + except);
    }
    return u;
}
```

Comment: Probably you resultset is empty

Comment: Check, if `ResultSet#next` returns `false`. If so, there is no result.

Comment: What about this  if(rs.next())
    {
      u.setName(rs.getString("user_name"));
    }

Comment: @qqilihq yeah, that was the problem) Thank you!

Comment: This is a horrible error message.  It is perfectly clear when you know what the problem is, and completely unhelpful when you don't.  An addition of `Did rs.next() return true? ` would be an immense improvement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was in resultset, it was empty.

Just replace this code

```
rs.next();

u.setName(rs.getString("user_name"));
```

with

```
if (rs.next()) {
    u.setName(rs.getString("user_name"));
}
```